# Multiplying numbers from the same table, different results in Sybase

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have a table in which a column has float values. I have to multiply them to get a result. Below is an example where in I get different results when i use the exp(sum(log.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there anyother way of doing this instead of taking each value and multiplying as a cursor?

```
select ( (1+ 0.01735538425366666)*(1+ 0.01768814252911706) -1) *100

declare @res numeric(38, 35), @v1 numeric(38, 35), @v2 numeric(38, 35)
select @v1=0.01735538425366666, @v2= 0.01768814252911706
select @res = ( (1+ @v1)*(1+ @v2) -1) *100
select @res

select (exp(Sum(log(1+a)))-1) * 100 from (select 0.01735538425366666 as a union select 0.01768814252911706 as a)aa

select (convert(numeric(38, 35), exp(convert(numeric(38, 35), Sum(convert(numeric(38, 35), log(convert(numeric(38, 35), 1+a)))))))-1) * 100 from (select 0.01735538425366666 as a union select 0.01768814252911706 as a)aa


-------------
create table #res(a numeric(38, 35), b float)
insert into #res (a, b)
select 0.01735538425366666, 0.01735538425366666 union
select 0.01768814252911706, 0.01768814252911706


select ((exp(sum(log(1+a))))-1) * 100 , ((exp(sum(log(1+b))))-1) * 100 from #res

--------------

&

select ( (1+ 0.01735538425366666)*(1+ 0.01768814252911706) -1) *100
```

Should give the same result right?

Comment: What were the two different results?

Answer (score 1):

Floating Point arithmetic is inherently inaccurate outside a certain range. Here's a link that goes into [gory detail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), but dig around on StackExchange or the web generally for floating point problems and you'll see that this comes up a lot.

Floating point has limits on accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

This will not give you the same results.

In the one example your using:

`select ( (1+ 0.01735538425366666)*(1+ 0.01768814252911706) -1) *100`

In the other example your running aggregate functions using the #res table.

`select ((exp(sum(log(1+a))))-1) * 100 , ((exp(sum(log(1+b))))-1) * 100 from #res`